# Neighboring skewed divs leave 1px gap between them

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have two skewed divs with linear gradient backgrounds, which should be lining up perfectly, yet they leave a 1px gap between them.

This fiddle demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/jesperryom/rn1ncd5u/

I have seen two suggested solutions (moving one div 1px to compensate, or giving them a transparent border), but none of those seem to work when the background color of the divs is a linear gradient as this image shows:

[Left has div moved 1px, right has transparent borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLmHh.png)

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}
```

Comment: I read that the problem is caused by the way transformed elements are rendered, so I tried with clip-path instead, but it produces the same problem: https://jsfiddle.net/jesperryom/1jLdz8y5/

Answer (score 1):

Box shadow are way harder to manage, but don't have that problem

```css
#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: skew(45deg);
    box-shadow: inset -22px 45px 80px -18px black;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: skewY(45deg);
    box-shadow: inset 45px -22px 80px -18px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```